# Where/When should I create the datacontext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

In my project i want the user select data provider and select his own Database File if exist;

the problem is when i start the application it crash and exite silently if database not exist, because each ServiceClass has instance of DbContext.
    i work with mvvm light + simpleIoc and i want:

-check database :

if exist ===> Main Window;

if not   ===> DbCon Window;

-managing ViewModelLocator Or Creating splash screen ?? 
what is the best practice for that;

and how to make DbContext Create in background;

```
  public class ViewModelLocator : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            //DbContext
            DbCon db = new DbCon();

            // ViewModel of Database connection window
            private DbConViewModel _dbConViewModel;

            //ViewModel for Main window
            public MainViewModel Main { get; set; }

            //
            public static ViewModelLocator Instance
            {
                get { return Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator; }
            }

            //Constractor
            public ViewModelLocator()
            {
                if (db.Database.Exists())
                {
                    Main = new MainViewModel(DialogCoordinator.Instance, new PeopleService(), new StatusService(),
                        new UserService());
                }
                else
                {
                    //I want show database connection Windows without Freezing
                    _dbConViewModel = new DbConViewModel();
                }             
            }
         }
```

Sorry for my terrible English ^_^ thank you

Comment: Please provide some code of what you're trying to do.

Comment: this is my code but i dont know Where or When should i call windows and datacontext;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:

`DBContext` is `IDisposable`, therefore it must either be disposed after usage (`db.Dispose()`) or - better - must only be used in a `using`-directive.

Secondly, you can avoid freezing by starting a separate task for the operation that takes a long time. Is `new DbConViewModel();` the operation that makes the UI freeze?

In summary, I suggest optimizing your code as follows:

```
    public class ViewModelLocator : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        // ViewModel of Database connection window
        private DbConViewModel _dbConViewModel;

        //ViewModel for Main window
        public MainViewModel Main { get; set; }

        //
        public static ViewModelLocator Instance
        {
            get { return Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator; }
        }

        //Constructor
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            //this will automatically dispose the DbContext as soon as the code leaves the directive
            using (DbCon db = new DbCon())
            {                    
                if (db.Database.Exists())
                {
                    Main = new MainViewModel(DialogCoordinator.Instance, new PeopleService(), new StatusService(),
                        new UserService());
                }
                else
                {
                    //this will execute the code in DoLongOperation() in an extra task, preventing the UI from freezing
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoLongOperation());
                }
            }
        }

        private void DoLongOperation()
        {
            _dbConViewModel = new DbConViewModel(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will try this ,even i know the problem is in the order of implimenting Data services

Comment: what is the best location for checking the existance of db ??

Comment: It depends on how frequently you use it. If you use the DB in only one or two specific places in your programme, check for existance before use. If you use it in several places all over the programme, check on appllication start

Comment: I use it in several places all over the programme,Thank you @GuyMontag